# How to import function from other module in airflow docker

Tags: docker, module, yaml, airflow, volumes

Basicly I'm trying to call a function from another files in airflow.
I want to run a python function from a different files using airflow-docker

I am using this image : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.1/docker-compose.yaml to run an airflow

Everything run smoothly when I am running a function within the same dag files.

[image: I am trying to import some function from another files within the same airflow repo]

But, when I go to my localhost airflow UI, I got error like this (no modules name includes)
[image: Error from airflow UI]

I already add one line code in docker-compose.yaml (includes) file below the environment volumes :
[image: Command includes were added]

But I still find the same error.

Is there anything I can do to fix the error ?

Any your helps will be appreciated much. Thank you !

Comment: Have you added `/home/work/voc/airflow/includes` to your `PYTHONPATH` inside the containers? The documentation for Airflow has examples how you can add custom modules for use in DAGs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html).

Typically I would add custom modules to the DAGs directory, and include an `.airflowignore` file in the root of the DAGs directory to make sure the scheduler doesn't parse them.

Comment: I realized that the another python script should be in the sama DAG's folder. That solved the problem actually

Comment: Remember to add the directory where you keep your extra python scripts/modules to an `.airflowignore`. The scheduler will parse all python files in the DAG directory every 30s by default, you can add significant load if you don't exclude these with this file.

Comment: Ah, I see..

Right now I'm experiencing error

`port 5432 failed: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`.

I already search the internet, added one liner to set max connection to 20000 like this in the bottom of postgres environment in docker-compose.yaml

`command: postgres -c 'max_connections=20000'`

but it still didn't work.

I will try to add `.airflowignore` file to reduce the load
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or changing the `airflow.cfg` configuration file, you can update the `docker-compose.yaml` file by modifying the volumes section as follows:

```yaml
...
volumes:
  ...
  - ./includes: /opt/airflow/plugins/includes
...
```

This will mount the `./includes` directory on the host machine to the `/opt/airflow/plugins/includes` directory in the container, making your custom modules available to Airflow without needing to modify any other configuration files or environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Airflow adds [plugins and config](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#built-in-pythonpath-entries-in-airflow) folder in PYTHONPATH.

To add additional folders, you need to set them explicitly

```
PYTHONPATH=$AIRFLOW_HOME/includes:$PYTHONPATH
```